# Why Python difflib close matches a first or second word for a two word arg

Tags: python, difflib

Finding suburbs in an address string using `difflib` module. Important that index position in string is recorded along with the suburb. Therefore storing suburb and index. At this point I get a different index for the two word suburb matches (`Lower Hutt` and `Point Howard`) The print statement shows this.

```
import difflib

# Sample address line with multiple suburbs
addressLine = '15 Long St,Lower Hutt, Wool Merch Sorter Newby Road, Point Howard Captain Short St, Eastbourne, Farmer'
# print("address line:",addressLine)

# A list of the separate words of addressLine
splits = []

# Provide a ref list of correct suburb spelling
burbRefs = ['Days Bay', 'Eastbourne', 'Lowry Bay', 'Lower Hutt', 'Point Howard', 'Wainuiomata', 'York Bay']

# A place to store found suburbs and string positions as tuples
burbList = ()

# Replace all commas, in the copied string, with spaces to treat each word equally
addressLine = addressLine.replace(',',' ')

# For a double space remove one of the spaces
addressLine = addressLine.replace('  ',' ')

# Begin by splitting the string, loaded from the list, using spaces (most reliable method)
splits = addressLine.split(' ')
print("splits check:",splits)

# Load each string token from list of strings 
for i in range(len(splits)):

    # Test for a suburb - difflib returns a list with a single string if found
    burbResult = difflib.get_close_matches(splits[i], burbRefs, n=1)
    print("index",i,"split",splits[i],"burb result:", burbResult)

    # If test for suburb successful
    if burbResult != []:
        # print("Suburbs found:",burbResult[0],"index:",i)
        # Extract string from list
        burb = burbResult[0]
        # Store the suburb and string index where found
        burbList += burb,i
        
        # Re-initialize result variable
        burbResult = ''
```

Output:

```
splits check: ['15', 'Long', 'St', 'Lower', 'Hutt', 'Wool', 'Merch', 'Sorter', 'Newby', 'Road', 'Point', 'Howard', 'Captain', 'Short', 'St', 'Eastbourne', 'Farmer']
index 0 split 15 burb result: []
index 1 split Long burb result: []
index 2 split St burb result: []
index 3 split Lower burb result: ['Lower Hutt']
index 4 split Hutt burb result: []
index 5 split Wool burb result: []
index 6 split Merch burb result: []
index 7 split Sorter burb result: []
index 8 split Newby burb result: []
index 9 split Road burb result: []
index 10 split Point burb result: []
index 11 split Howard burb result: ['Point Howard']
index 12 split Captain burb result: []
index 13 split Short burb result: []
index 14 split St burb result: []
index 15 split Eastbourne burb result: ['Eastbourne']
index 16 split Farmer burb result: []
```

With reference to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) The `word` arg to `difflib` is the `split[i]`. However the example is using two words. But joining the words with an underscore is not an option. The `possibilities` argument is a matching double word in `burbRefs`. The third arg `n=1`is the maximum number of close matches to return.

Why is the index for `Point Howard` 11 when it should be 10 if consistent with the other double word `Lower Hutt`?